# How can I put a timer when using int 21 ah = 01h

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Well basically, I am trying to make a simple quiz game, once the question is prompted, I need to make a 9 second timer for the user to input their answer or else they'll lose the game. I am still very new with assembly language and would like to seek help from you guys.

I have tried using:

```
mov ah,1h
int 21h
```

to get get the user character input, basically a,b,c or d.

I have also made a looping 9 second timer but I really don't know where to put it in, as I can't put it on top of `mov ah,1h` or below it as it will not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using DOS or a DOS emulator for your quiz - otherwise the "int 21h" instruction would not make any sense.

As far as I know there is no function in DOS that allows waiting for a given time for input; all functions will wait endlessly.

You may use the BIOS functions AH=0 and AH=1 of interrupt "int 16h" to query the keyboard (AH=1 will check if a key is pressed and AH=0 will read the key itself). You may use the BIOS function AH=1 of interrupt "int 1Ah" to query the time.

Most DOS and BIOS interrupts are well documented in Ralph Brown's interrupt list:

http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm